# Incrementing Value in Cookie

Tags: cookies

I've got Cookie Plus and Mo' Variables installed. I'm trying to set, get and increment a value in a cookie. Here's my test script:

```
{if "{exp:cookie_plus:get name="aa_seq"}" == ""}
{exp:cookie_plus:set name="aa_seq" value="1" seconds="0"}
Setting<br>
{/if}

Cookie: {exp:cookie_plus:get name="aa_seq"}<br>
{exp:cookie_plus:set name="aa_seq" value="<?php echo {exp:cookie_plus:get name="aa_seq"} + 1; ?>" seconds="0"}
```

I tried it with PHP on input and output, and they both FUBAR.

Would appreciate any pearls of wisdom. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the first conditional.. but you could try this for the last line if you want to continue using the add-on. The original last line will fail because you've set it up to need to run cookie_plus both before and after the php increment.

```
{!-- Set PHP to input --}

{if "{exp:cookie_plus:get name="aa_seq"}" == ""}
    {exp:cookie_plus:set name="aa_seq" value="1" seconds="0"}
    Setting<br>
{/if}

<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['aa_seq']))
{
    $aa_seq_value = $_COOKIE['aa_seq'] + 1; 
} else {
    echo "No cookie was found."
}
?>

Cookie: {exp:cookie_plus:get name="aa_seq"}<br>
{exp:cookie_plus:set name="aa_seq" value="<?php echo $aa_seq_value; ?>" seconds="0"}
```